# Get post ID for Shortcode based off Atts

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm looking to create a shortcode for my Posts that I can input an $atts which would be a slug for a post in my custom post type which I can than use that slug to get that post's ID so I can pull in meta data in the shortcode.

```
add_shortcode('stats', 'stats');
function stats($atts) {
array(
    'hero' =>'',
);

$HeroSlug = $atts['hero']; 

$HeroPostID = I need this to grab the post ID based off the the $atts 'hero' which is the post's slug

$output =  echo get_post_meta($HeroPostID 'hero-sub-name', true);

return $output;
}
```

So in the shortcode I would put in [stats hero="illidan"] illidan is the slug for that custom post type post that I want to grab the ID from I'm just not sure how to than take that slug and grab the ID of that post so I can use in the $HeroPostID variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add_shortcode('stats', 'stats_func');
function stats_func($atts) {

```
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'hero' => ''

    ), $atts ) );
    if(strlen($hero) < 1){ return; }
    $the_slug = $hero;
    $args=array(
        'name' => $the_slug,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $my_posts = get_posts($args);
    if( $my_posts ) {
        $HeroPostID = $my_posts[0]->ID;
    }
}
```

//edit That's how i would do it.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work except how can I make what is inputed as the hero attribute for the shortcode = $the_slug since the shortcode is going to be [stats hero="illidan"] or [stats hero="nova"] I need to have what ever i put as the hero attribute be put in under the name in the array.

Comment: Ah yes, i didn't need $the_slug, just replaced it with $HeroSlug under name since it was already defined and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Mark as answered :) have a nice day!

Comment: Would you be able to explain this line for me "if(strlen($hero) < 1){ return; }" and the purpose of it? I'm still learning PHP so I get all of it just not sure the purpose for that if statement.

Comment: If the string length (strlen($hero)) of hero is less than 1 (i.e they did not supply an argument), return (end the function) and return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `get_the_ID()` ?
This will give the current post ID on which the shortcode is being displayed

Comment: I'm not looking for the post ID that the shortcode is being displayed on but the post ID of the slug of which ever it put in as hero="" so if I put [stats hero="illidan" I need the post ID from the post with the slug illidan.

Comment: In that case visit this link
http://blog.wpessence.com/get-post-by-slug-name-id-methods/